# How to change home page meta title in magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2.3, home-page, page-title

How to change meta title in magento2.3? I am not able to find the title of the home page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your Magento admin panel and go to:

```
Content > Pages > Find your home page
```

See the screenshot below:-

[image]

(If you can't find which CMS Page your homepage is set as, you can confirm this by going to Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> Default Pages -> CMS Home Page, which will show you which page is being used)

Add your meta title and flush the Magento cache (run the `php bin/magento c:f` command in CLI)

Finally go onto the front-end of your website and check the changes. (See screenshot below):-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php


namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Controller\Test;


use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    private $pageFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context,
                                PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Execute action based on request and return result
     *
     * Note: Request will be added as operation argument in future
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $pageFactory = $this->pageFactory->create();
        $pageFactory->getConfig()->getTitle()->set('Your Title');
        return $pageFactory;
    }
}
```